# Link for migrated post is in negative under "Top network posts" in user's profile

Tags: bug, migration, top-network-posts

[Set time zone without root privilege](https://serverfault.com/questions/986419/set-local-time-without-root-privilages?noredirect=1) was migrated from Server Fault to Unix & Linux with the answers. [One of the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544658/322920) is among the top network posts of [Eduardo Trápani](https://askubuntu.com/users/1001631/). But the post shows only score with no title in the user profile.

[image]

And interestingly the link contains negative post id. When I click on the *empty* title, it redirects  to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/-2147482064/544658#544658.